# Implement Heap with generics in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, heap, comparable

I want to implement a Heap based on an Array. However, this Heap is should be callable with an Array of either only elements that implement the Comparable interface or with an additional Comparator (so if no Comparator is given it is assumed every element can be compareTo with one another). Then I want to check for its validity. It doesn't work because the heapCondition for extends Comparable can not be called.

```
public class Heap <T>{
Object[] tree;
Comparator<T> comparator;

public <T extends Comparable<T>> Heap(T[] tree){
    this.tree = tree;
}

public Heap(T[] tree, Comparator<T> comparator){
    this.tree = tree;
    this.comparator = comparator;
}

/**
 * defines the heapCondition default is set so the Heap is a minHeap (parent is smaller than their children)
 * @param parent parent node
 * @param child child node
 */
public <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean heapCondition(T parent, T child){
    return parent.compareTo(child) < 0;
}

public boolean heapCondition(T parent, T child){
    if(comparator == null){
        // go into the heap condition where to Comparable is assumed
        heapCondition(parent,child);
    }
    return comparator.compare(parent,child) < 0;
}


/**
 * @return boolean whether or not the current tree fulfills the Heap condition
 *
 */
private boolean valid(){
    for(int i = 0; 2*i+2 < tree.length; i++){
        // returns false if the condition is not met for one of the children
        return !(!heapCondition((T) tree[i], (T) tree[2*i+1]) || !heapCondition((T) tree[i],(T) tree[2*i+2]));
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your implementation `Heap <T>` and `public <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean heapCondition` are not the same `T`s. The generic method creates other `T` and *shadows* `T` from the class definition. That's why your `public boolean heapCondition` can't call `public <T ...> boolean heapCondition`.

Actually, you can't require `T` to be `Comparable` in the case when `Comparator == null` and `T` to be any class otherwise. `java.util.TreeMap` implements something similar. It uses `compareTo` when `Comparator == null`. But this logic is done by using runtime casting and throwing `ClassCastException` when the object is not `Comparable`. Here is JavaDoc of `java.util.TreeMap`

```
     /**
     * Constructs a new, empty tree map, using the natural ordering of its
     * keys.  All keys inserted into the map must implement the {@link
     * Comparable} interface.  Furthermore, all such keys must be
     * <em>mutually comparable</em>: {@code k1.compareTo(k2)} must not throw
     * a {@code ClassCastException} for any keys {@code k1} and
     * {@code k2} in the map.  If the user attempts to put a key into the
     * map that violates this constraint (for example, the user attempts to
     * put a string key into a map whose keys are integers), the
     * {@code put(Object key, Object value)} call will throw a
     * {@code ClassCastException}.
     */
    public TreeMap() {
        comparator = null;
    }
```

And here is `getEntry` implementation which casts elements to `Comparable`:

```
    final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
        // Offload comparator-based version for sake of performance
        if (comparator != null)
            return getEntryUsingComparator(key);
        if (key == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
    ...
```

### The solution

You need to remove all generics except for `Heap <T>` definition. Also, when your `comparator == null`, you're not returning the result, thus making infinite recursion. And in your `valid` method you're always returning after the first iteration.

Here is how your heap may look like.

```
class Heap<T> {
    T[] tree;
    Comparator<? super T> comparator;

    public Heap(T[] tree) {
        this.tree = tree;
        this.comparator = null;
    }

    public Heap(T[] tree, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        this.tree = tree;
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    /**
     * defines the heapCondition default is set so the Heap is a minHeap (parent is smaller than their children)
     *
     * @param parent parent node
     * @param child  child node
     */
    public boolean heapConditionComparable(T parent, T child) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Comparable<? super T> comparableParent = (Comparable<? super T>) parent;
        return comparableParent.compareTo(child) < 0;
    }

    public boolean heapCondition(T parent, T child) {
        if (comparator == null) {
            // go into the heap condition where to Comparable is assumed
            return heapConditionComparable(parent, child);
        }
        return comparator.compare(parent, child) < 0;
    }


    /**
     * @return boolean whether or not the current tree fulfills the Heap condition
     */
    boolean valid() {
        for (int i = 0; i < (tree.length - 2) / 2; ++i) {
            // returns false if the condition is not met for one of the children
            if (!(!heapCondition(tree[i], tree[2 * i + 1]) || !heapCondition(tree[i], tree[2 * i + 2]))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at `TreeMap` which deals with a similar problem, but I don't find its approach very elegant. I would use static factory methods for better type control and assign a default comparator for natural ordering. That way you don't have to worry about which comparison method to call:

```
public static <T> Heap<T> create(T[] tree, Comparator<T> comparator) {
    return new Heap<>(tree, comparator);
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Heap<T> create(T[] tree) {
    return new Heap<>(tree, Comparator.naturalOrder());
}

private Heap(T[] tree, Comparator<T> comparator) {
    this.tree = tree;
    this.comparator = comparator;
}

public boolean heapCondition(T parent, T child) {
    return comparator.compare(parent, child) < 0;
}
```